# MS Word VBA x32 ->x64 conversion, replacement for SetParent?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an old Word document with VBA built in x32 and I need to updated it to work in x64. I've been going through finding the broken x32 declarations and replacing them, but I've having trouble finding a replacement for the following.

```
Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ron de Bruin: Excel Automation](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm) is a lifesaver when it comes to converting API calls.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetParent Lib "user32" Alias "SetParent" (ByVal hWndChild As LongPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
#End If
```